# Iotivity communication between linux and android

Tags: android, linux, client-server, communication, iotivity

I'm trying to work on the iotivity server-client communication,
but the server runs on android (java sdk) and the client runs on linux (Ubuntu, C++) platform.

I tried running them in the same Wi-Fi network,
but the client couldn't find the server resource.
Even when I tried to search the server with the server IP address,
it still couldn't find it.

Does any one know how to connect these two devices, or
is there any documentation that I can refer to?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Normal IoTivity discovery uses udp multicast, make sure your wifi router isn't blocking/filtering such.  Are you able to make it work with a client and server running on the same host?

There are plenty of notes on wiki.iotivity.org, but we've been hearing it's not that easy to find necessary information.  Documentation bugs are welcome too...